# Where does bash prompt escape sequence \h get the hostname from?

Tags: bash, centos7, hostname, ps1

`\h` is a bash prompt escape sequence that expands to the hostname. Where does it get the hostname from? On my system it shows a value that I cannot find anywhere, not in `hostname -f` or `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/hostname` or `/etc/sysconfig/network` or `$HOSTNAME`. So I'm wondering where it's getting it from. My system is Centos 7.4. I know there are hidden places where things such as UUIDs are stored, and I seem to recall that I've come across a similar hidden hostname type of issue in the past, but I can't remember the details.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: `bash` can run on non-Unix systems, and it is reasonable to ask here about the semantics of the `\h` escape.

Comment: So it turns out that systemd has its own `hostnamectl` stuff which includes storing and accessing hostname from hard drive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [bash source code](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) you'll see in `shell.c` that it calls [gethostname(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname), a POSIX system call that retrieves the hostname from the kernel.

```c
/* It's highly unlikely that this will change. */
if (current_host_name == 0)
  {
    /* Initialize current_host_name. */
    if (gethostname (hostname, 255) < 0)
      current_host_name = "??host??";
    else
      current_host_name = savestring (hostname);
  }
```

This is not necessarily a canonical string. The kernel doesn't actually know the machine's network hostname. It just reports back whatever was passed to [sethostname(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sethostname). To quote from the [uname(2) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/uname):

> On the other hand, the [hostname] is meaningless: it gives the name of the present machine in some undefined network, but typically machines are in more than one network and have several names.  Moreover, the kernel  has  no  way  of  knowing  about  such things, so it has to be told what to answer here.

On non-Linux systems without gethostname(2), bash falls back to [uname(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/uname). If uname(2) isn't even available then it simply displays "unknown". You can see that logic in `lib/sh/oslib.c`:

```c
#if !defined (HAVE_GETHOSTNAME)
#  if defined (HAVE_UNAME)
#    include <sys/utsname.h>
int
gethostname (name, namelen)
     char *name;
     int namelen;
{
  int i;
  struct utsname ut;

  --namelen;

  uname (&ut);
  i = strlen (ut.nodename) + 1;
  strncpy (name, ut.nodename, i < namelen ? i : namelen);
  name[namelen] = '\0';
  return (0);
}
#  else /* !HAVE_UNAME */
int
gethostname (name, namelen)
     char *name;
     int namelen;
{
  strncpy (name, "unknown", namelen);
  name[namelen] = '\0';
  return 0;
}
#  endif /* !HAVE_UNAME */
#endif /* !HAVE_GETHOSTNAME */
```

`\h` isn't updated if the hostname changes. The value is cached at startup when the shell is initialized.

```
[jkugelman@malkovich]$ hostname
malkovich
[jkugelman@malkovich]$ sudo hostname kaufman
[jkugelman@malkovich]$ hostname
kaufman
[jkugelman@malkovich]$ bash
[jkugelman@kaufman]
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably (just a guess) uses the [gethostname(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html) system call (which is handled by the kernel, as all [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) are...)

BTW, [GNU `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) is (as most packages of your Linux distributions are) [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software); so please **download its source [code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4.12.tar.gz) and *study* it;** [*use the source, Luke!*](http://www.usethesourceluke.com/) and [*open the source more*](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/open-your-source-more/), please.

A more interesting question is how that information is cached by `bash`. Does it call `gethostname` at every command? You might also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find out.

---

<sup>Of course, take the habit of studying the source code of free software every time you are curious. And use `strace` -and the `gdb` debugger- to understand their dynamic behavior.</sup>

A French singer, [G.Bedos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_Bedos), told us "La liberté ne s'use que si on ne s'en sert pas", that is

> *Freedom wears out if you don't use it*.

<sup>(translation is mine, I am French but not a native English speaker)</sup>

---

So next time, please **dive into the source code** of free software. It is important to **exercise your freedom**, and that is what [**free software is about**](http://www.fsf.org/about/what-is-free-software).