# whether the environment variable exported in c function will be available in parent shell?

Tags: c, shell

I was writing a shell on which i am calling a c function where i exports a variable. In below example

```
my_test.c
int main()
{
   setenv("MY_NAME","kk_rathor",1);
   // get and print MY_NAME works here 
}

my_test_Sh.sh  
#!bin/sh
test
echo $MY_NAME // does not works here
```

I am getting not getting my name on printing $MY_NAME However if i am exporting anything in shell i can get it on test.c.

Is the scope of variable exported from test.c is only in that function only. if not then what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks
Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: It's the realization of a basic rule "*A child can never affect the environment of its parent.*" (were we only so lucky in real life...)

Comment: Your question is indeed not clear, and lacks a real [MCVE]

Comment: You should improve your question, not comment it.

Comment: you can't achieve directly as you trying because setenv sets for own process. you can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416638/set-environment-variables-in-c)

Comment: BTW naming your program `test` is very confusing, since [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) is a standard utility (and often a shell builtin). Use some other name next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) and [setenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) and [putenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html)

But environment variables (actually, the entire [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) and process state) are local to their [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (e.g. your shell) and changing it does not affect those in other processes (except *future* child processes obtained with [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)). Hence changing an environment variable -or any other memory location, or the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), or [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), etc...- in a child process don't affect its parent process (or any other existing one). See also [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

You should consider other kinds of [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) such as [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s or [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)-s (and perhaps [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)  with [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)). You might want to have some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) above [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

Read [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and some book like [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/).

BTW, most existing [Unix shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). So you can download and study their source code. And you could [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) them. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47061807/841108).

Comment: Thanks already read those.
However i wasn't  sure whether C program varible will be propagated to the parent shell.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables are local to the current process, and are propagated (=copied) to *child* processes *on creation*. When you set `MY_NAME` in the C program it gets set just in its process, it cannot be propagated to the parent (i.e. the shell).

If you want to provide some data to the shell, write it on standard output.

Comment: Thanks..
It wasn't clear to me whether my C program varible will be propagated to the parent.

Comment: About writing the data to the standard output. Can you please elaborate or provide me the direction where i can proceed.

Comment: Nothing fancy - just print to standard output using `printf` and the like and capture the output using `$(...)`. But probably this is not what you want, you should clarify better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: How can i capture the output in the shell ? I have updated the question head. Will it serve my purpose ?